# PHPMyadmin import CSV creates new table

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import some data into a MySQL 5.5.31 table from a CSV file using PHPMyadmin 4.0.0.

When I try to import, the import "works" but it creates a new table rather than imports into the current table - the new table is assigned a sequential name by PHPMyadmin and, whilst the data is viewable, the data is not usable as the table does not contain a unique column.

Here is a screenshot of the settings I am using to import which also shows I am trying to import into the table:

[image]

And here is the result I get from PHPMyadmin:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? I have tried searching for the "The following structures have either been created or altered" message but found nothing here and only a few things on Google but none of the Google responses were of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in phpMyAdmin and it has been fixed since version 4.0.1. See 14 item under 4.0.1.0 (2013-05-14) section of the [change log](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php) file. Upgrade to 4.0.1 or a version greater than that.

Answer (score 2):

Not allowed to comment on Madhura Jayaratne's reply, but - because people trying to import ODS will look at this thread - it is worth pointing out that it is only partly correct.  CSV has been fixed but the same bug still exists for ODS in phpMyAdmin 4.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of phpmyadmin try SqlYog .SqlYog is userfriendly.Just try it